# How to change titles (facet_col )in imshow (plotly)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to plot several images with `imshow` from plotly and give each image a title.

My code is

```
fig = px.imshow(numpy.array(img1,img2), color_continuous_scale='gray', facet_col=0, labels={'facet_col' : 'status'})
fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False).update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)
fig.show()
```

and the result looks like

[image]

**However**, I would like to replace `status=0` with `original` and `status=1` with `clean`. Is there an easy way to achieve this result?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by

```
fig = px.imshow(
  numpy.array(img1,img2), 
  color_continuous_scale='gray', 
  facet_col=0
)

fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False).update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)

for i, label in enumerate(['orignal', 'clean']):
    fig.layout.annotations[i]['text'] = label

fig.show()
```

It would be nice, if there would be a shorter way e.g. passing the list of labels directly to the `imshow` command. However, I did not find any possibility to do that.

Comment: I know this question has already been solved, but I wanted to suggest another way of solving this issue that might be more simple: `fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))` [source](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/#controlling-facet-spacing)

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate the answer by @DerJFK, however, it won't support multirows.

This trick will fix the problem:

```
item_map={f'{i}':key for i, key in enumerate(['orignal', 'clean'])}
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=item_map[a.text.split("=")[1]]))
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs, adding parameter 'x' with a list of names should solve it.

```
fig = px.imshow(numpy.array(img1,img2), 
    color_continuous_scale='gray', 
    facet_col=0, 
    labels={'facet_col' : 'status'}, 
    x=['Orginal', 'Clean'])
fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False).update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: The x options throws 
ValueError: The length of the x vector must match the length of the second dimension of the img matrix.

The labels in x seems to want to label each pixel along the second dimension. Which ist not the title. But thanks