# Plotly Facet_col subplots titles

Tags: subplot, facet

I read many posts similar to my questions but for some reasons they still don't work.
I'm working on the well known plotly database 'tips'. I want to show 2 subplots by 'sex' and then edit both subplots' titles. I start from this code:

```
df=px.data.tips()
names={'Femmine':'Plot1','Maschi':'Plot2'}
fig=px.box(df,x='day',y='tip',facet_col='sex')
```

Now I'd like to edit the default subtitles outcome('sex=Female', 'sex=Male') and replace them with
two names i stored in the dictioanry names. I tried this:

```
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=str(names.keys())))
fig
```

But the output gives me this:

[image]

Really, i know the solution is there but ...I simply can't find it. Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer here: [How to change titles (facet_col )in imshow (plotly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046467/how-to-change-titles-facet-col-in-imshow-plotly)

```
df=px.data.tips()
names={'Femmine':'Plot1','Maschi':'Plot2'}
fig=px.box(df,x='day',y='tip',facet_col='sex')

for i, label in enumerate(names):
    fig.layout.annotations[i]['text'] = label

fig.show()
```

Note that this works because your dictionary keys are the title you wish to update.

Otherwise, if you wanted the value instead (Plot1, Plot2), you should instead use:

```
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(names.items()):
    fig.layout.annotations[i]['text'] = value
```

Comment: Thanks man, once again I underrated the value of 'enumerate'...